# Android - Dialog box in a fragment that belongs to 2 activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have got a fragment that belongs to activity "Activity_Joueurs". In this fragment there is a dialogue box. Hence the code below for a positive click in the dialog box :

> ( (Activity_Joueurs) getActivity() ).doPositiveClick()

This is working well. Now I would like to reuse this fragment from another activity "Activity_Pseudo". And it is where I'm stuck. How can I have this part of the code activity independent ?

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(R.string.question_delete_joueur)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ( (Activity_Joueurs) getActivity() ).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                }
                        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start working with `Interfaces`, instead of casting the activity to it's concrete class, like you do it at the moment:

```
( (Activity_Joueurs) getActivity() ).doPositiveClick();
```

... you first define an interface:

```
public interface IFragmentCallback {
   public void doPositiveClick();
}
```

... then you let BOTH your activites implement this interface, example for the `Activity_Joueurs`:

```
public Activity_Joueurs extends Activity implements IFragmentCallback{
  //...
  @Override
  public void doPositiveClick(){
    //Implementation
  }
}
```

... next in your `Dialog` you change the call to something like this:

```
( (IFragmentCallback) getActivity() ).doPositiveClick();
```

... et Voilà: Activity Independent.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a class with a static method to return a Dialog, then it can be called from any Activity.

```
class MyAlerts{

    public static Dialog getAlert1(Activity activity, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener){
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle(R.string.question_delete_joueur)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, listener).create;

    }

}
```

It can be used as follows from any Activity

```
MyAlerts.getAlert1(this, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do something

        }
    }).show();
```